# Does anyone know a way to capture webcam video at a constant framerate?

Tags: c#, webcam, video-capture, recording, frame-rate

OK, so I have been having a bit of a tough time with webcam capture, and am in need of help to find a way to capture the video at a consistent frame rate.

I have been using Aforge.AVIWriter and Aforge.VideoFileWriter, but to no avail, and have also typed any related phrase I can think of into Google.

I have had a look at the DirectShowLib, but am yet to find it any more accurate.

The video must have a minimum frame rate of 25fps, it is also to be shown in sync with other data which is collected at the same time.

I have also tried an infinite loop:

```
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (recvid == false)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (writer.IsOpen)
            {
                Bitmap image = (Bitmap)videoSourcePlayer1.GetCurrentVideoFrame();
                if (image != null)
                {
                    writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(40);
            }


        }
```

Even though this is more accurate for timing, the user can see that the fps changes when they watch the video and view data at the same time.

Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot think of a way to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two main issues that i can see:

writer.write()  is it happening in a seperate thread? if not it will take time and hence the timing might not be accurate.

second thread.sleep() says  that sleep for **at-least** 40 ms not **exactly** 40 ms.. to get better results  reduce the wait time to 5 ms and do it in a loop.. use the systems time to actually figure out how long you have slept for and then take a frame capture.

Hope this helps

Comment: essentially you want to minimize the computation done by this thread between each sleep and ensure that sleep is accurat...  print out the system time in ms everytime you go in to sleep and come out of sleep.. might not be a difference of exact 40 ms

Comment: Well, it has helped as much as I have come to think anyone can, thank you.  I have continued to search for a way to sync the video, and the best that I can find is using Aforges VideoFileWriter, which has a TimeStamp property, did not notice this when I was searching, but it seems to be the closest that I can find and seems to mostly keep it within 200ms

Answer (score 1):

With most web cameras (except maybe rare exceptions and higher end cameras that offer you fine control over capture process) you don't have enough control over camera frame rate. The camera will be capturing stream of frames at its maximal frame rate for the given mode of operation, esp. capped by resolution and data bandwidth, with possibly lower rate in low level conditions.

No `Thread.Sleep` is going to help you there because it is way too slow and unresponsive - in order to capture 25 fps the hardware needs to run smoothly without any interruptions and explicit instructions to "capture next frame now" pushing new data on the one end of the queue with you popping captured frames on the other end. You typically have a lag of a few video frames even with decent hardware.